# php switch first case not working properly

Tags: php, function, switch-statement, conditional-statements

I have this function where first case is executed when `$time` **= 0**

```
    function time_spended($time){
        switch($time){
            case $time > (60*60*24*365):
                $time /= (60*60*24*365);
                return number_format($time, 2, '.', ',') . " year" . ($time > 1 ? "s":"");
                break;
            case $time > 60*60*24:
                $time /= 60*60*24;
                return number_format($time, 2, '.', ',') . " day" . ($time > 1 ? "s":"");
                break;
            case $time > 60*60:
                $time /= 60*60;
                return number_format($time, 2, '.', ',') . " hour" . ($time > 1 ? "s":"");
                break;
            case $time > 60:
                $time /= 60;
                return number_format($time, 2, '.', ',') . " minute" . ($time > 1 ? "s":"");
                break;
            default:
                return number_format($time, 2, '.', ',') . " seconds";
        }
    }
```

*For example:*

```
echo time_spended(0); // 0.00 year
```

*Instead of:*

> 0.00 seconds

Comment: Just a heads up but everything is going to be added as a plural since `$time` is always going to be greater than 1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Function returns `0.00 year` (*in other words, result from the first `case`*), because `$time = 0` in `switch` evaluates to `false`, and as `$time > (60*60*24*365)` is `true` it returns result from the first branch, *viz*:

```
[0 == true] => [false == true] => [false]
```

To make it work you should use `switch(true)` instead of `switch($time)`, it should work the way it is shown below:

```
[true == (0 > 60*60*24*365)] => [true == true] => [false]
```

[**Example**](https://eval.in/319693)

Comment: I tend to agree with Cristik's answer that `switch` is not the right tool for the job in this case.

Comment: @Mike: I may be wrong, but in the php docs should be an example of such `switch` using. Anyway, it is all a matter of one's choice or/and coding style.

Comment: @notulysses On the [switch page](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.switch.php) there are several comments using `switch(true)`, but nothing in the actual documentation content. But I agree, it's a matter of one's personal coding style. I just tend to do a double take if I see it in code. `if/elseif/else` just seems more readable to me in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Conditions in `switch` should be in brackets.

```
function time_spended($time){
    switch($time){
        case ($time > (60*60*24*365)):
            $time /= (60*60*24*365);
            return number_format($time, 2, '.', ',') . " year" . ($time > 1 ? "s":"");
            break;
        case ($time > 60*60*24):
            $time /= 60*60*24;
            return number_format($time, 2, '.', ',') . " day" . ($time > 1 ? "s":"");
            break;
        case ($time > 60*60):
            $time /= 60*60;
            return number_format($time, 2, '.', ',') . " hour" . ($time > 1 ? "s":"");
            break;
        case ($time > 60):
            $time /= 60;
            return number_format($time, 2, '.', ',') . " minute" . ($time > 1 ? "s":"");
            break;
        default:
            return number_format($time, 2, '.', ',') . " seconds";
    }
}
```

Comment: That switch will always go to the `default` branch, the brackets don't help at all

Comment: And reason being is `$time` is being passed in as `0` which also equates to `false`. First statement returns false because `$time` is less than 31mil, so it's executed.

Answer (score 0):

You are not using the `switch` statement correctly. A `switch` statement is used to pick among several values. A more suitable/clear approach would be to implement the logic with `elif`'s:

```
function time_spended($time){        
        if($time > (60*60*24*365)) {
            //...
        } elseif ($time > 60*60*24) {
            // ...
        } elseif($time > 60*60) {
            // ...
        } elseif($time > 60) {
            //...
        } else {
            return number_format($time, 2, '.', ',') . " seconds";
        }          
}
```

A correct example of `switch` would be:

```
switch($currentDayOfTheWeek){
    case 'Monday': // ...
    case 'Tuesday': // ...
    case 'Wednesday: // ...
    // and so on
    default: // cause it's goo practice to have a default  branch
}
```

**Edit:** Thanks Mike for the `elif` comment :)

Comment: Note PHP uses `elseif` not `elif`

Comment: Oops... language mix-up :P. Thanks for the note, will update my answer.